# Focussing and/or selecting an input element slow on IE with large count of input tags inside the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, forms, internet-explorer

My company provides an ERP solution which is dependant on using IE because of some bad decisions years back (using behaviors for dynamic html), so I can in no way use another browser. And right now it is restricted to IE8. And about 40.000 installations are out in the fields...

To the problem:

Normally a page in our application has about 150 - 200 input tags inside the dom. Using them via JavaScript is no problem.

But: Now we have a page (for a single customer only) with a huge table (about 1500 table rows), where each row has about ten (editable) input fields inside some columns, so we have about 15000 input tags inside the dom. This single page uses jQuery, which is not in use for the rest of the product.

First of all: Scrolling the table (inside a div) is terribly slow on IE (eats up all CPU).

Second (and my main concern right now): If I want to change the focus and / or select text inside one of the input tags, IE slows down to a crawl.

If I have for example a table with only 50 rows everything works fine, but IE slows down the more rows and input fields are being added. If I only put textual information in the table cells, IE has no problems with it.

So it really is the input-field which is causing the slowdown, but is there any way around that?

I am open for suggestions - I have tried using editable divs, but I cannot get them to 100% emulate a singleline-input field (I need onblur events, click events and so on).
Currently I am also thinking about making this single page of the product compatible to Chrome and using Chrome Frame plugin for IE in order to display the page

FYI: All events but the onblur event are registered on the table element. The onblur element get registered on all input fields inside a row once a user clicks on an input field (and the onblur event for the last active row is being removed).

Thank you all for sharing some thoughts...

***Update***
I have changed the code so that no input fields are inside the table. Only after a row gets activated, the cells with editable content get an input element.
The adding / removing of those input cells is rather quick (20 - 40 ms), but the problem with selecting and focusing on a field remains the same...
With a table with 190 rows IE took about 1600 - 2100 ms to execute ".focus()" and ".select" on an input element inside the table.
I am at my wits end - right now I consider making this single page compatible to other browsers than IE and tell our client to install the Chrome Frame plugin. Or another solution would be to program a rich client for the purpose - all which will take more time than what is being paid for...
Remember that the table layout works fine as long as not too many rows are inside that table...

Code:

Example of a table row:

```
  <tr id="POS_5096" class="ROWSELECTED" poscount="0" ordnernr=
  "ROOT" timestamp="00000000003091FB">
    <td>
      <input class="CHECKONE" type="checkbox" name="wn_folder_dnd">
    </td>
    <td name="FOLDERPATH" dttype="string" dbvalue="002">
      <a href=
      "../Sales/AuftragPosRec.aspx?auftrag=200146&amp;accessID=5096"
      target="_blank">002</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="CHECKONE" title="Textposition" disabled type="checkbox"
      name="TEXTPOS" dttype="i2" dbvalue="0">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="taketextpos" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="CHECKONE" title="Durch Mehrung / Minderung verändert"
      disabled type="checkbox" name="WN_MMCHANGED" dttype="i2" dbvalue="0">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="0">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 140px" value=
      "dfgdfgdfgdfnbndfs" name="NAME" dttype="string" dbvalue=
      "dfgdfgdfgdfnbndfs" jquery16409152079553898877="55">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takename" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td name="NAMEINTERN" dttype="string" dbvalue="PDW-1500 PDW-1500">
      <a href="../Masterdata/ArtikelInfoRec.aspx?artikel=114080" target=
      "_blank">PDW-1500 PDW-1500</a>
    </td>
    <td title="04020asasa" name="ARTIKELGRUPPE" dttype="string" dbvalue=
    "04020">
      04020
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="1">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 35px" title="04" value="04"
      name="RABATTGRUPPE" dttype="string" dbvalue="04"
      jquery16409152079553898877="56">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="pickrabattgruppe" src="../Style/fieldicons/picklist.gif">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takerabattgruppe" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td name="HERSTELLER" dbvalue="103736.001">
      <img title="Sony Europe Limited (B)" name="popupadresse()" src=
      "../Style/field-icons/goto-this-dataset.png">
    </td>
    <td name="LIEFERANT" dbvalue="">
      <img title="" name="popupadresse()" src=
      "../Style/field-icons/goto-this-dataset.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="pickwn_lieferant" src="../Style/fieldicons/picklist.gif">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="2">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 50px" value="2,00" name=
      "MENGE" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="2.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="57">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style=
      "BORDER-BOTTOM: #809db7 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #809db7 1px solid; WIDTH: 10px; BORDER-TOP: #809db7 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #809db7 1px solid"
      name="WN_AUFWAND_BEISTELL" dbvalue="" clickevent="pickbeistell">
         
      </div>
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="3">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 55px" name="PREISME" dttype=
      "string" dbvalue="Stück" disabledvalue="Stück"
      jquery16409152079553898877="58">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="pickpreisme" src="../Style/fieldicons/picklist.gif">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takepreisme" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="WN_UVP" dttype="number" dtscale="2"
    dbvalue="0.00">
      0,00
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="4">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 105px" value="0,00" name=
      "WN_EKPREIS" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="59">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takewn_ekpreis" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="5">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 30px" name="WN_EKWAEHRUNG"
      dttype="string" dbvalue="USD" disabledvalue="USD"
      jquery16409152079553898877="60">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="pickwn_ekwaehrung" src="../Style/fieldicons/picklist.gif">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takewn_ekwaehrung" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="6">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 45px" value="1,00" name=
      "WN_EK_SONDERRABATT" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="1.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="61">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takewn_ek_sonderrabatt" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="7">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 45px" value="0,00" name=
      "WN_EK_SONDERRABATT2" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="62">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takewn_ek_sonderrabatt2" src=
      "../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="WN_EKPREIS_FINAL" dttype="number"
    dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00">
      0,00
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="WN_AUFSCHLAG" dttype="number"
    dtscale="2" dbvalue="10.00">
      10,00
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="MARGE" dttype="number" dtscale="2"
    dbvalue="100.00">
      100,00
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="WN_AUFSCHLAGREAL" dttype="number"
    dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00">
      0,00
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="8">
      <input class="CHECKONE" type="checkbox" name="WN_EKFIX" dttype="i2"
      dbvalue="0" clickevent="dataChange">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takewn_ekfix" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="9">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 105px" value="0,00" name=
      "NETTO" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="63">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="10">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 35px" value="0,00" name=
      "RABATT" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="64">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takerabatt" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="11">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 35px" value="0,00" name=
      "RABATT2" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="65">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takerabatt2" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="12">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 35px" value="0,00" name=
      "RABATT3" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="66">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takerabatt3" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="13">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 35px" value="0,00" name=
      "WN_MARKUP" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="67">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takewn_markup" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="WN_MARKUPPREIS" dttype="number"
    dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00">
      0,00
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="WN_GESAMTRABATT" dttype="number"
    dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00">
      0,00
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="STKERLOES" dttype="number" dtscale=
    "2" dbvalue="0.00">
      0,00
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="DECKUNG" dttype="number" dtscale=
    "2" dbvalue="0.00">
      0,00
    </td>
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" name="ERLOES" dttype="number" dtscale="2"
    dbvalue="0.00">
      0,00
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="14">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 35px" value="0,00" name=
      "MRABATT" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="68">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takemrabatt" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td sizcache="0" sizset="15">
      <input style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 35px" value="0,00" name=
      "RABATT4" dttype="number" dtscale="2" dbvalue="0.00"
      jquery16409152079553898877="69">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img name="takerabatt4" src="../Style/MenuIcons/down.gif">
    </td>
    <td name="USERPOS" dttype="string" dbvalue="21">
      <a href=
      "../Sales/AuftragPosRec.aspx?auftrag=200146&amp;accessID=5096"
      target="_blank">21</a>
    </td>
    <td style="DISPLAY: none" name="TEXT"></td>
    <td style="DISPLAY: none" name="SORTIERUNG">
      a
    </td>
    <td style="DISPLAY: none" name="HERSTELLERNAME">
      Sony Europe Limited (B)
    </td>
    <td style="DISPLAY: none" name="LIEFERANTNAME"></td>
    <td style="DISPLAY: none" name="POSITION">
      21
    </td>
    <td style="DISPLAY: none" name="ARTIKEL">
      114080
    </td>
    <td name="WN_ORDNERNAME"></td>
    <td style="DISPLAY: none" name="WN_LIEFERANT"></td>
    <td style="DISPLAY: none" name="WN_MARKE"></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Are you binding a jQuery each loop to all of the inputs? If so you'd be far better off using a javascript for loop, the performance is 91% faster than jquery's each

Comment: I agree with Jamie, also try binding the events to each TR tag instead of the table.  jQuery has to search through every single row to find the field that receive the event's action.  In this case, it may be worth binding a handler many times to each TR tag rather than once to the TABLE.  Normally this isn't true... but it just may help here.

Comment: John is correct with that comment also, it's actually faster in jQuery to say $('table').find('tr') than $('table tr') because CSS selectors move backwards :)

Comment: I do not use any jQUery "mass processing" on the table.
In fact simply the rendering of the table itself (=scrolling) ist slow, and the focusing / selecting of text inside input tags.
I already use MS own suggestions for faster table rendering (TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed, and setting the width of each column), which does not seem to help (but does no harm, either).

Comment: And, by the way, since the mouseclick is fired on the table and not on the next input element, I simply have to look inside the event object to get the dom element under the mousepointer during the click event, so no jQuery search here as well. This is not what is taking time, it is the function call to .focus and .select

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the script in addition to the HTML, I can suggest only two things:

1) Profile, profile, profile. Either use a better browser (Chrome/Safari+Devtools or Firefox+Firebug can help) or try to use some of MS' dev tools (I have no experience with using these for profiling, but from what I recall MS's script debugger can do it) or [DynaTrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/), which I've found to be pretty good for working with IE. Find what is slow, and fix it.

2) Get rid of all the input boxes, and convert the cells to input boxes on click. In jQuery, use a delegate for this. Something along the lines of:

```
$('table').delegate('td', 'click', function() {
    // Switch back and forth between input and text here.
});
```

This should eliminate pretty much any slowdown from script. I am skeptical about the claims in the comments claiming jQuery has to 'search' for the element which is blurred - this should be available on the event object, as far as I understand. I don't follow why jQuery would have to search for it - but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: In fact, using a delegate like that slows everything down even more. That is why I simply register the clicks on the table element, and then inspect the event model as to which element of the table was really clicked on.
But what you are saying with swapping simple text data for the real input fields I started trying yesterday, but still takes some work.

Comment: I already profiled the slow selecting event, and it really are the .focus or .select calls which slow eveyrthing down (on my experimental table, all the code of finding the correct input cell, saving data of the formerly selected cell into the database take about 50 - 200 ms, whereas the following call of .focus and .select take 1600 - 2300 ms)

Comment: OK, how do you do the '(and the onblur event for the last active row is being removed).' part? Do you have a reference to that handy or are you looping? Again, showing the actual code would help...

Comment: The actual code is copyrighted and about 10000 lines long (4000 client side / 6000 server side). And it also gives hints about our customer, so I would have to rewrite a lot.

The removing of the onblur event is as follows:

`$("#POS_" + highlightRow.LAST).removeClass("ROWSELECTED").find("input:enabled").unbind("blur");`


This takes about 2 - 7 ms, it really is the .focus and .select call to the clicked input element of the next row which "kills" IE...

Mhhm, I do not really understand code formatting inside comments...???

Comment: Are there other select/focus handlers on the page that are being triggered? Now that you've changed the page as suggested by your update, I'm not really sure what else to try. The only thing that might still help you is to know that jQuery special-cases blur/focus so they bubble. You could try calling the 'real' DOM focus method and trigger any required event handlers manually, to see if that fixes anything?

Comment: I already do not use jQuery's own focus / select code, because of the performance overhead.
Usinge the direct DOM methods does not help very much (some ms).

I have made progress making the page compatible to chrome (some layout and some code changes are still required), so I think I will stick with my idea of using the Google Frame plugin in IE for that page.